# Do bounties lower the top n% score on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, stack-overflow-jobs

My inner narcissist forces me to regularly check my profile on careers.stackoverflow.com.

There's this little badge stating top 10% for c#. Given the sheer number of people here on SO this probably doesn't mean much, but it looks nice.

Now if I offer a bounty worth of 100 reputation on Stack Overflow, this does lower my reputation. But does it affect the algorithm calculating this top n% badges on careers?

Lets' assume that I have just qualified the threshold, which gives rewards me with the 10% badge and I set up a bounty for of 100 reputation for

- a) a question not tagged with c#
- b) a question tagged with c#
- c) a question tagged with c# and asp.net

Given these 3 cases: If a bounty affects the calculation, how is it affected? Is the reputation loss split equally amongst all tags?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can remember the "top user" calculation uses *votes* as it needs to be specific to that tag.

Your reputation is the sum of (upvotes + acceptances + bounties earned) - (downvotes + bounties started), there's no way of getting back to the specific reputation earned in each tag from this aggregated value.

So bounties won't lower the value.

Comment: - Losses to Rep-cap and SPAM/Offensive flags